# Displaying members in teams

Tags: typescript, aurelia

Im trying to display the number of users in each team. I have an department object that has departmentId and with it i would want to display users.

Im displaying my users in a modal with this function.

```
 async selectTeam(index: any) {
    this.selectedTeam = this.teams[index];
    this.usersToShow = this.tenantUsers.filter(item => !this.teams.find(team => team.id == this.selectedTeam.id).users.map(x => x.id).includes(item.id));
}

<a click.delegate="selectTeam($index)" class="rounded-circle" data-toggle="modal"
                                href="#modal-form3">
```

If i have 2 teams each in his own row, how would i display length of the each team?